# Are horror movies haram?

Tags: halal-haram, movies

I've heard some people said that everything made me scared is forbidden in Islam, Is that right?

If so, are horror movies haram in the light of Quran and sunnah?

Comment: ok, what if horror movies does not scare me?

Comment: :), Because that i said everything made me scared :D

Comment: Are movies Halal in the first place?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When someone ask a

> Is ... haram in Islam?

question, we should response with

> What makes you think that ... is haram in Islam?

Islam is not a religion full of harams. If something is not explicitly said to be haram in Quran, or is clearly forbidden by Rasul, then it is not haram under normal conditions.

And don't forget that, every halal action can be haram under extreme condition, and every haram action can be halal under extreme conditions.

For example;
Eating sugar is halal. But if you have a diabetic disease, and you blood glucose ratio is much above normal, you cannot eat sugar. Because it is suicide.
Eating meat of pig is haram. But if you are alone in desert and starving, it becomes halal.

We can't say that watching horror movie is haram. But it can be haram if you enjoy watching people being slaughtered, or if you are wasting your precious time with watching too much movies (e.g.; 6 hours everyday).

A muslim must protect himself/herself from turning in a wrong way (from siratal mustakim - the rightful path defined in Quran). This kind of self protection is called `taqwa` in Quran. Every kind of detail (like watching horror movies) are not mentioned in Quran and Sunnah; a muslim must have taqwa and make the optimum choice for himself/herself. We are all responsible for making the correct choices about our daily problems.

Comment: Your words are true
,but is horror movies have a negative effect in any way it was!?

Comment: You right, But when i hear some people say it's not allowed at all, I must know if they are right or not.

Comment: @MYamanT Amount of negative effect a movie will give to you differs from movie to movie, and watcher to watcher. There are some movies, you get scared, but you return to normal as soon as they end. But there are some movies which leaves you psychological changes and change in view of life. Some sensitive people may change their behaviors and/or try to do the same thing in the movie after watching them. For example, after watching the Saw series, someone may start to think that bad people must be punished by the same torture methods, and do the same think he/she saw in the movie in real life.

Comment: @MYamanT (continued) I still cannot say that watching it Haram. But a person must have taqwa and be careful. If he/she feels himself/herselve sensitive, shouldn't watch that movie in the first place.

Comment: @MhdAljobory There is no exact answer like "They are haram" or "They are halal". The border between haram and halal is not that sharp as you expect it to be. If Quran said that horror moview were haram, then we could clearly say "They are haram". But there is no direct order about it, so it is left to us. We must be careful, we mustn't indulge to the Earthly desires too much, we must always have taqwa. The one with higher taqwa will be in higer degree in the after life.

Comment: @Ahmad Han I agree with you they can not say about something that is haram without clear evidence;
And I did not say it is haram absolute sense, but meant that the many of movies containing scenes of forbidden.
For example smoking, there is no evidence from the Qur'an or the Sunnah that it is haraam in itself, but scientists absolute denied it because it harm and damage in general, regardless of the special cases

Comment: I couldn't appreciate you more, Ahmed. You summarized pretty much everything in your answer. Very very well written. Wish I could get in touch with you

Answer (score 2):

Allaah has enjoined on the Muslims to preserve its members from doing all that affects the human nature which is created by the worship of God, and that the conservation of that member enters in thanking those great blessing that God bestowed it upon His slaves.

> ولا تقف ما ليس لك به علم، ان السمع والبصر والفؤاد، كل أولئك كان عنه
>   مسؤلا الاسراء:36
>
> Do not follow that of which you have no knowledge. Verily the ear, the
>   eye, the heart, each will be questioned Al-Isra:36

In other words, should not only have to move away from the obvious forbidden, but everything affects pure human Fitrah that God created them

and no one should argue that the the bad effects of those films on the communities in general, **what may be a violation of the Islamic faith, educate the violence and to facilitate the crime, and other ill effects.**

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/125535) which should answer your question.

It basically says that in movies in general these days, you will see the following:

```
display of women's awra
display of men's awra
tight cloths
revealing cloths
their soft voices
enticing walks
dancing
music
```

All these things are haraam, and as all these things will be found in movies, that kind of suggests that movies are haraam.  However, I guess if you can find a movie which doesn't have any of those haraam elements, then it could be concidered non haraam?

Answer (score -2):

Salam, First of all movies are made by people who are fully controlled by the shaitan, shaitan is the head of bollywood and hollywood and music and women are his tools.

Shaitan will get you to watch a movie by one or another way. Ex: scary, sexy, fighting, family, love and so on the goal is the same to get you in the game of the SATAN move by move. Show you naked body parts, good dressed women or men so you dont like your wife anymore. Show you how much fun it is to be rich, drugs, alcohol, ect... it is a teaching and trick of the shaitan to get you with nice relaxing brain programming logic.

A movie can only be HARAM if its objective are negative and not on the sheri law the QUARAN, now most movies have harm teaching such as kissing, adultery, women dancing, and to make love priority above all, seeing sex in TV will become normal for the family, showing body parts and other HARMAM things which can turn you and your family in the wrong path with no time. Your house will become clean from angels and dirty.

Horror movies can make you weak, sick, scared and afraid of death, you must be strong in your life and let your faith in the path of Allah (SWT) and you must only be afraid of the creater  Alla (SWT).

If you look in the past our old grand parents were much stronger in their faith and less afraid in life due no such media data.

Most Indian films are based on false loving and dying for the woman or for man they prize love above all that exist which is wrong, it does not teach you why Allah (SWT) sent us here for. As you can see for them loving a girl or boy is everything and if anyone from family comes in between their love, is a devil.

In this world Allah sent us for a propose not to sing songs and running after every women we see on the street and our focus should be on the commandments of Allash (SWT).

REAL MOVIES - REAL WOMEN

You 'll get lots of dream drinks and dream women in JANNAT Inshallah only if you can keep your short life TAQUA strong and not fall to weak worldly few days life. The women in JANNAT are much much more better and beautiful then you can imagine compared to those false bollywood or hollywood models and even 1000's of times much beautiful,  you will have all your phantasies come true in Jannat with your dream women if you have Taqua.
Allag (SWT) will give you all you wanted in much better deal and plus his gifts.

People having fun in this life following media and movies will have no land in there after and will have no pass to enter the REAL clubs, real joys and dream life of Jannat.

English movies are mostly based on leading you toward devilish things and against right  path, as you can see most movies will have sex speech and sex scenes, clubs, drugs, drinks, gays, brain washing media, worldly life ect.

If you are watching a movie make sure your family does not watch the bad and haram parts cause it is HARAM to watch such things which can lead you to adultery and worldly life.

What ever we watch our brain will keep it in the memory and shaitan will do his best to lead you to such way so you do the same. IF you program your brain and time with good things your brain will think of good deeds and will gain more for here after.

Be careful on what you can avoid with your eyes and ear as it will make your inner IMAN weak and also make you afraid in life, you will not be able to stay strong.

Hope that helps brother...

Comment: please add some Islamic references to support your answer.