# Is watching movies permissible in Islam?

Tags: fiqh, movies

Are movies allowed in Islam? I am speaking about sci fi, romance, horror, comedy or cartoon movies.

Reading [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/are-horror-movies-haram-in-islam) makes me think only horror movies are an exception rest all are allowed.

I think educational movies that teach us about Islam or some school/college related work are allowed. But what about the aforementioned types of movies?

Answer (score 5):

Let's tackle this issue from 50,000 feet first. In Islam, everything that is not worship is permitted, until proven guilty. So the default ruling, on everything, is permissibility.

Therefore, the question that comes up is: are there elements in some movies that would make them impermissible?

Let me attempt this socially instead of from a pure fiqh perspective. Here are some points to consider:

- Excessive movie watching, like excessive anything, can be a waste of time.
- Most movies and shows (even news!) contain women dressed provocatively (according to the Islamic boundaries).
- Movies are steeped in music, [which we've discussed already](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/237/music-in-islam).
- The messages and beliefs behind many movies can run contrary to Islam.

About this last point, [Islam-QA says](http://islamqa.com/en/ref/3324/movies):

> [...] If these stories include lies, such as Darwin’s theory
>   (evolution), and other things that are contrary to the facts stated by
>   Islam and the facts of natural science, then the Muslim should avoid
>   them, and keep himself busy with something that will be of use to him,
>   such as learning good things or doing righteous deeds or reading true
>   stories and historical accounts and so on. Many of the movies and
>   novels that are known as “Science Fiction” include a lot of kufr, such
>   as putting life and death in the hands of some created being, giving
>   creatures the ability to create from nothing, saying that scientists
>   in laboratories can create from nothing, making inanimate things come
>   alive, creating life from a fossil that has been dead for many
>   millenia, or travelling to the future then coming back to the present.
>   All of this is impossible, and no one knows the unseen except for
>   Allaah. Some of these novels and movies also include clear
>   contradictions of historical facts that are mentioned in the Qur’aan
>   and Sunnah, such as man’s creation and his life on earth. When the
>   Muslim indulges in reading these books or watching these movies, it
>   shakes his belief or at the very least wastes his time and keeps him
>   busy with something that is of no benefit to him. Some people claim
>   that this is just entertainment and a way of passing time, but
>   entertainment is not permitted if it is haraam [...]

All of this seems to indicate little good, or a lot of evil, around movies.

Comment: I know some families who watch (mostly kids) movies: they filter first with kids-in-mind.com, and they're very quick to mute if the music is a lot. It's a valiant attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I believe cartoons may be allowed unless they are contrary to Islamic beliefs or have inappropriate content.
If I am wrong May Allah forgive me as this is merely my own theory and I have not researched my theory yet.