# Is it Islamically okay to watch the new "Messiah" series on Netflix?

Tags: dajjal, tv

The messiah series shows the idea of Dajjal...and the realities revolving around it. Are Muslims supposed to stay away from such show or can they watch it gain some knowledge?

Comment: better not, no benefit anyway, and it is permissible to dislike their videos

Comment: How would you gain any knowledge from a work of fiction?

Comment: It kinda shows the realities behind dajjal and just shows how he's gonna take over the world and stuff....IDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've watched an episode.

I don't think this series is showing the idea of Dajjal at all. In Islam Dajjal is One-eyed man. Also, 70 thousands of Jewish from Isfahan will follow him in the beginning.

For me, I don't think they mean Dajjal. I think they mean Jesus. He also messiah but the true messiah not the Liar one (Dajjal). Even though, the text written is bad and some quotations from Quran are used in wrong way.

There are many resources to look if you want to gain knowledge about messiah Dajjal or the messiah Jesus peace be upon him but not this resource.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Jazakallahu Kahir

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works. Thanks for your answer. Check out other Qs and As and hope you stick around.

Answer (score 1):

Before I try answering the question I want to highlight the folllowing:

- If I understood the question correctly, it is regarding if you are allowed to watch the mentioned series.
- The second question *"but can I do it if I gain some knowledge from it?"*
  Basically, the second question is only relevant if the answer to your main question is "no". In that case it might be better to ask another more general question like; *"Am I allowed to do/watch something haram if my intent is to gain knowledge in order to perform better spiritually?"* This is not in scope of this answer.
- The answer is not regarding if you should watch movies or not, or do something "better" with your time.
- I won't mention why you shouldn't watch the series.

---

Basically, watching this series goes along the ruling watching any other movie or series. See for instance [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/is-watching-movies-permissible-in-islam) and [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/are-horror-movies-haram?) question. Also as a note on one of the answers saying you shouldn't watch it if it goes against Islam: Is the movie trying to convince you about believing on something that goes against Islam or not? If not, then it's hard to call it haram. In that sense you can't even watch the news.

### Perspectives

I haven't watched the series, but as I said, the ruling goes a long wacthing any other series. And **maybe** there could be positive to watch it in order to get a sense of how other people interpretate the islamic view of this topic. This could then be used to remove misconceptions, or maybe open up a new perspective for you (which might be good if its positive interpretation).

As an example of what I mean with perspectives, @Mohammad Aldawsari states in his question the following:

> I don't think this series is showing the idea of Dajjal at all. In Islam Dajjal is One-eyed man

This could be the case, but after reading about the series it is clear that the producer wants to leave some room of speculations if this is the dajjal or messiah they are picturing in the series.

But certiantly, what he mentions in his answer comes from an approved opionen from an islamic standpoint, for instance it is mentioned in several hadiths that he is oned eyes (see [this](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/97/36)).

The following will be opinion based and hypothetical.
If we look back on the jews, we will notice that they had some kind of reasons of not following Jesus, either religous convictions, or maybe pride. The same thing for the Christians and Jews in the Prophets Muhammads (saw) time. 
So the possibility that muslims in the future might not think that the dajjal is dajjal might be because of some religous convictions, and therefore maybe follow him.

For instance, reading the hadith saying it will be written "Kafir" between dajjals eyes. What if that doesn't literally mean that it will be written between his eyes? What if it means that a "true" muslim will know he is the dajjal?
The same question goes to the hadith saying he will be blind on his *right eye*. What if he really isn't literally blind on his right eye? But it might mean something else? (See for instance [meaning of right and left in Arabic)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29813/the-origin-of-the-word-left-and-right-in-arabic)

So, if the dajjal comes with something that somehow goes against a convication how you perceive him, and the series might help you get perspectives of an interpretation of how he might be, then maybe that is good, to help you get perspectives which will make you cleaver enough to avoid him if he appears in your path.

Answer (score -2):

I have watched the entire series and it was the most interesting piece of art that I have ever seen in my life. I also recommended it to all my family and friends and will continue to do so. The series talks about a man who is trying to wake people up and remind them that Allah has given them dominion over earth. Whatever you want to call him, Al-Masseih, Jesus, The Messiah, Dajjal, all is irrelevant because the actor never actually mentions his name nor does he mention his religion (keep in mind that he was arrested and was taken for questioning several times, yet he never mentions his name or religion). It was those who want to credit him called him Messiah and those who want to discredit him called him Dajjal, whereas those who had no religious foundation referred to him as another “Al Baghdadi” or a terrorist. Now let me get to the good part and my personal favorite:
When the character shows up in Syria to motivate people to stand in their grounds and reminded them of the Quranic verses and how they have suffered more than any other civilization on this planet for years. It opened up the minds of some people and specially the young ones. He later asks his followers to get rid of all of their weapons into a hole on the ground and march with him in the name of peace. Consequently, when he and his followers got to the borders of Israel, the border guards saw a huge amount of refugees heading their ways. Shortly after calling for backup they realized that they can’t shoot them because they had no weapons on them not to mention the mainstream media cameras soon showed up at the scene which put Israel on the spot light should they do anything stupid like kill a peaceful and armless people. The funny thing is, we keep ridicule any other opinion that is different than ours. We, however, forget that should enough people gather and peacefully march to go back to the holy land just like what happened in the series then we can get back Jerusalem over night under international law. There is a lot of knowledge in that show and if enough people watch it then Israel will be no more. 
Remember that Ghandi freed India from the British occupation with absolutely no guns simply by obtaining the western knowledge before he went back and enlightened t he people who were ignorant of such reality. 
Please keep open mind and let your heart decide. After all, the enemy of knowledge is belief.